Sagemaker does not recognize training job to launch inference
I successfully launched a training job in sagemaker. However, when I try to use the model to run inference, sagemaker is unable to find the model.
import sagemaker
from sagemaker.transformer import Transformer
from sagemaker.model import Model

# Set session parameters
sagemaker_session = sagemaker.Session()
role = sagemaker.get_execution_role()

# Input paths
model_s3_path = 's3://sagemaker-us-west-1-6584743930/pytorch-training-2024-05-16-15-18-34-042/source/sourcedir.tar.gz'
input_s3_path = 's3://some-bucket/inference/beauty_annotations_simple_transformer.csv' 
output_s3_path = 's3://some-bucket/inference/ouput/'

# Define instance type
instance_type = 'ml.m5.large'

# Model
model = Model(
    model_data=model_s3_path,
    role=role,
    framework_version='2.0',
    entry_point='inference.py',
    source_dir='./source_dir'
)

# Transformer
transformer = Transformer(
    model_name=model.name,
    instance_count=1,
    instance_type=instance_type,
    output_path=output_s3_path,
    assemble_with='Line',  # method of output assembled
    accept='application/jsonlines',  # output format
)

# Launch batch transform job
transformer.transform(
    data=input_s3_path,
    content_type='text/csv',  # input format
    split_type='Line',  # output split method
)

# Job wait
transformer.wait()

Error

ValueError: Failed to fetch model information for
pytorch-training-2024-05-16-15-18-34-042. Please ensure that the model
exists. Local instance types require locally created models.


Per the tag description, [ml] is for the family of programming languages (OCaml, SML, etc...). Use [machine-learning] for machine learning.

To use a custom model for batch transforms, you need to first to invoke Model.create() to register the model with SageMaker.

In a CreateModel request, container definitions include the
ModelDataUrl parameter, which identifies the location in Amazon S3
where model artifacts are stored. When you use SageMaker to run
inferences, it uses this information to determine from where to copy
the model artifacts. It copies the artifacts to the /opt/ml/model
directory in the Docker container for use by your inference code.

You can find further details in How SageMaker Loads Your Model Artifacts.
